# Encodeing results are not working

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a program written in Delphi 4 and trying to convert it to delphi xe10. One part i do not understand is this.

```
    Cmd[0] := 2;                   // Number of equipment to talk to
    Cmd[1] := 22;                  // My device address
    Cmd[2] := 0;
    MResults.Lines.Add('Reciving...');
    Refresh();

    Srlen := High(RecBuff);                               

     Ret := GpListen(@Cmd, @Srlen, @RecBuff);              // gets returned value
    if CheckRet('GpListen', (Ret and $FF), csBuf) = 0 then 
    begin
        RecBuff[Srlen] := Chr(0);                            // ??
        MResults.Lines.Add(RecBuff);               // returned 
        //csBuf := Format('????', [Srlen]); ////?some error??
    end;
```

The issue is RecBuff (RecBuff:array[0..9999] of Char;) It starts off full of #0  like so:

[image]

but as soon as

```
Ret := gpListen(@cmd, @srlen, @recbuff);
```

is ran recbuff now looks like this:

[image]
alot of japan char.  how do i get this to encode onto the memopad correctly.

Comment: I have inserted the images for you. Two tips for next time: 1) We don't need these big screenshots, only the relevant local variables section will do 2) Never ever put code in your questions without specifying the variable types (we now have to assume what animal *cmd* is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
RecBuff:array[0..9999] of Char;
```

to

```
RecBuff:array[0..9999] of AnsiChar;
```

and see if it works. This may prompt some changes other places in the code.

In Delphi 10, a "Char" is a 2-byte entity (16 bit character, UniCode) as opposed to Delphi 4, where it is a 1-byte entity (8 bit character, ANSI). The common format for both compilers are "AnsiChar", which is an 8-bit character.

You'll probably also have issues with STRING variables which are now filled with 16-bit characters and not 8-bit characters.

Also - read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) before going any further in your conversion.

Comment: Perfect.  and thanks for link this unicode / ansi conversion is killing me.

Comment: Also see Embarcadero's migration documentation: [Unicode in RAD Studio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio)

Answer (score 1):

In Seattle strings and chars are Unicode by default.

Exchange with device usually is carried on through Ansi chars (one-byte) buffers.

So use AnsiString, AnsiChar, PAnsiChar etc

RecBuff:array[0..9999] of **Ansi**Char;

We have already discussed this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077071/gb-ip-function-not-working-correctly)